# Any visualization tools for HyperTable namespaces?

Tags: user-interface, data-visualization, hypertable

Are there any visualisation tools to hypertable namespaces? Comming from the RDBMS world used to viewing table data and entries, are there any well know tools that can provide a 'table-like' view of keyspaces? GUI based would be great!

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/andysoftdev/ht4n/tree/master/src/ht4n.Explorer

A simple explorer with a nice UI.